Change order of triple power $x^{y^z}$
I need somehow convert triple power like
$$e^{n^x}$$ where
$x \ne 0$ and $n \ne 0$
to
$$f(n)^{g(x)}$$ where $f(n)$ is purely function of $n$ (it does not know about $x$ existance and cannot use it) and $g(x)$ is purely function of $x$ (it does not know about $n$ existance and cannot use it)
Please note the order of power in the original formula. We first take power of $n^x$ and then exponentiate it, $e^{(n^x)}$
I work in complex domain

It's impossible: take two logarithms and observe the behavior of partial derivatives.

Either that or I made a calculation mistake, in which case it's possible and the solution is given by integrating those partial derivatives you computed.

It certainly seems like an unlikely expectation.

Suppose there are such functions $f(n), g(x)$. Then we can take two logarithms to get
$$x \ln n = \ln g(x) + \ln \ln f(n)$$
Both sides must be defined for sufficiently large $x$ and $n$. Now let $x_1$ be a large number and $x_2 = x_1 + 1$. Substituting them in $x$ and subtracting the two equations, we get
$$ \ln n = \ln g(x_1 + 1) - \ln g(x_1). $$
But this cannot happen because the right hand side cannot depend on $n$, but the left hand side evidently does. This means there is no $g$ to make it work.

It is sad that i cannot do this, but your answer makes sense. thx
